# Bootstrap IntroJS step number not aligned correctly in Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, intro.js

This is a Question/Answer as I solved my problem while reading a related question about IntroJS.

The problem was that the step numbers were not aligned correctly in their red circles.

The problem lies in that the script was designed using Bootstrap 2. In Bootstrap 3 it is misaligned.

To make the correction I went into the `introjs.css` file and changed:

```
.introjs-helperNumberLayer {
    width:  20px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

to:

```
.introjs-helperNumberLayer {
    width:  30px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

Now the numbers are centered in the red circle.

Comment: Leave your question as only the question, answer it below and mark it as correct so it doesn't stay as an open question. Anyway, your contribution would better fit a blog of your own, and not so much the StackOverflow system.

Comment: Or post is as an answer to the related question about introJS

Answer (score 0):

Updating the introjs.css to widen the circle a bit and drop the padding also fixes the issue (I thought taking the circle to 30px made it look too big):

```
.introjs-helperNumberLayer {
    padding: 0px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
}
```